# how to post data to rest api JSON from Body android c#

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin.android, http-post, webapi

Can Anybody Help me to find out the solution? I need to register data using POST Method send a parameters from Body.I am using this Code

```
  public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Signup(Register register)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result=null;
        try
        {
            string url = Constant.url + "api/services/app/Account/Register";
            HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
            var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(register);
            result = await _client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF32, "application/json"));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
            return result;
    }
```

But I am getting 500 Internal Server Error.Please Help me.

Comment: Check your api code and api error logs to get more information

Comment: Without knowing what you are sending to the server and what the server expects, nobody can help you with your problem. 500 also indicates there is a problem at the server. So you will have to inspect and  the server's code to see, what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public static  Signup_Root Check_xsignup(Register register)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        string resultt = "";
        Signup_Root lp =null;
        try
        {
            string jObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(register);
            StringContent content = new StringContent(jObj, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            MediaTypeHeaderValue mValue = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            content.Headers.ContentType = mValue;
            string url = Constant.url + "api/services/app/Account/Register";
            HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
            result =  _client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
            if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                resultt = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                lp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Signup_Root>(resultt);
            }
        }
        catch (Java.Lang.Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return lp;
    }
```

Try this, It will work

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this:

```
public class MakeRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

        protected void onPreExecute(){ }

        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(AppConstants.DEMO_API); // here is your URL path
                //params....
                JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("type","claim");
                postDataParams.put("data", jsonObject);
                Log.e(TAG, postDataParams.toString());
                postDataParams.put("ctx","j");
                postDataParams.put("email", "abc@gmail.com");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(60000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(60000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST"/* meathod */);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                //response....
                int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

                    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
                            InputStreamReader(
                            conn.getInputStream()));

                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line="";

                    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }
                    in.close();

                    // getting JSON string from URL
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                    return json;
                }
                else {
                    return new JSONObject();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();

                return new JSONObject();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
            
        }
    }
```